# Does the Microsoft Arc mouse support middle click and drag functionality?

Tags: mouse

Writing software that I want to have click drag functionality for the middle mouse button (Like most 3d modelling software).

I think that is one awesome mouse design, but I read on the Microsoft website that it supports double middle click for middle click? It does say it can be programmed, but not specifically if it supports normal middle click and drag functionality.